# Unwanted Pytorch data duplication across multiple GPUs

Tags: linux, pytorch, gpu

I am having a strange issue with pytorch on a machine that has 2 GPUs. When I run the following code with VRAM of both GPUs empty:

```
Python 3.11.6 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Oct  3 2023, 10:40:35) [GCC 12.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import torch
>>> dev = torch.device('cuda:0')
>>> a = torch.rand(1000,1000,1000, device=dev)
```

The 'a' tensor gets copied over to both GPUs even though I explicitly piped it to GPU #0.
[image: GPU usage]

However, the same thing doesn't happen on another system with similar hardware with the same code.

Specs of the faulty setup:

```
GPU: Quadro P6000 (2x)

$ conda list torch*
# packages in environment at ....:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
pytorch                   2.1.0           py3.11_cuda11.8_cudnn8.7.0_0    pytorch
pytorch-cuda              11.8                 h7e8668a_5    pytorch
pytorch-mutex             1.0                        cuda    pytorch
torchaudio                2.1.0               py311_cu118    pytorch
torchtriton               2.1.0                     py311    pytorch
torchvision               0.16.0              py311_cu118    pytorch
```

Update: I have determined this a CUDA issue (by manually using cudaMalloc from a c program).

Comment: does `torch.cuda.device_count()` return 2?

Comment: @Karl Yes, it returns 2.